# Why would a <button>, with attribute type="submit", not be submitted with the form when using HTMLFormElement.submit()?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I happen to have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?> enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <button type="submit" name="identifier" value="wikipedea_form">
    Add Post
  </button>
</form>
```

I use jquery to submit this form as

```
$("form").submit();
```

This doesn't send the post data `$_POST["identifier"]`. I assume jQuery uses `HTMLFormElement.submit()` under the hood. [The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) say that:

> `<input>` with attribute type="submit" will not be submitted with the form when using HTMLFormElement.submit()...

I think the same applies to the `button` tag as well. Just to be 100% sure I am asking here. May be it depends on the browser etc etc...

So, Would `<button>` with attribute `type="submit"` not be submitted with the form when using `HTMLFormElement.submit()`? Please quote official documentation to back up your answer.

Comment: You submit the `<form>` element, NOT a button, and the value of the submit button will not be passed in the request because you didn't actually clicked on the button

Comment: Disabled elements are not submitted with the form. Use a `hidden` input instead

Comment: No disabled controls get submitted

Comment: But your quote is specifically about `HTMLFormElement` so perhaps I didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: @AlonEitan I have edited the question to submit a form rather than a button. Just realized what you said.

Comment: [The submission algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm) item 8. says: "_Let entry list be the result of constructing the entry list with form, __submitter__, and encoding._". When you use `submit` method of the form, _submitter_ is null. Nevertheless the submitter element (or the lack of it) disabled form control elements are not added to the entry list [5.1 in The algorithm to construct the entry list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-form-data-set).

Comment: I guess your example is incomplete. What will trigger jQuery form submit event? If button is not disabled, it will fire form submit event. If button is disabled, it will not fire submit event. Now you are showing code which does nothing with the button, but jQuery submitting directly the form. Your example does not correspond with the question, confusing.

Comment: It's also notable, that jQuery's submit method doesn't behave natively, it runs the attached submit event handlers, the native method doesn't do that. There might be also some other differences, which are against the standard.

Comment: @lubosdz I have removed the `disabled` attribute to keep things simple. In my original code, I remove that with jQuery if certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

Only *successful* controls are submitted in normal form submission.

Submit buttons are only successful if they are used to submit the form (or if the form is submitted via Enter in a single text input in which case the default submit button is successful). This lets you distinguish which button was used to submit the form in cases such as:

```
<button name="action" value="like">Like</button>
<button name="action" value="dislike">Dislike</button>
```

Trigging form submission with JS bypasses the selection of a submit button.

---

5. For each element field in controls, in tree order:

   1. If any of the following is true:

      - The field element has a datalist element ancestor.
      - The field element is disabled.
      - **The field element is a button but it is not submitter.**
      - The field element is an input element whose type attribute is in the Checkbox state and whose checkedness is false.
      - The field element is an input element whose type attribute is in the Radio Button state and whose checkedness is false.

   **Then continue.**

— https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-the-form-data-set

---

If you want to submit data with a form every time it is submitted, regardless of how it was submitted: Use `<input type="hidden" ...>`